# React How to Return Divs styled based on Multi-Dimensional Array Values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working in React. I have a multi-dimensional array with the values 0 or 1. I would like to run these through an iterator and add a class if the value is truthy, then return divs. And for every array value, I would like to build the board by dynamically changing the inline style 'top' and 'left' so every board piece gets dynamically positioned as it is run through the iterator. So far, I have tried flattening the array, then running through a map function. And I have tried two-levels of map. I can get either to produce the required number of divs, but they're all on top of one another. So it's basically a board with 64 tiles on the same spot. I am unable to get the style to dynamically update for each pass through the iterator. I can get this to work fine in vanilla javascript by just iterating through the array and appendChild each produced div.

I would like the end result to produce a bunch of divs (tiles), with the same class, some have an additional class to show they're populated, and all have slightly different 'top' and 'left styles' to produce a grid of these tiles.

Here is my code, which produces a lot of divs on top of one another.

```
class CheckerBoard extends Component {
    render() {
        let rows = this.props.rows.slice();
        let flattened = _.flatten(rows);
        let tiles = _.map(flattened, function (mapped) {
          for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
          if(mapped){
            return <div className="checkerTile filled" style={{top: `${i * 50}px`, left: `${j * 50}px`}}></div>
          } else {
            return <div className="checkerTile" style={{top: `${i * 50}px`, left: `${j * 50}px`}}></div>
          }
            }
          }
        });
      return (
        <div className="CheckerBoard">
          {tiles}
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Post up your class definitions too, could be a CSS formatting issue

Comment: If I change the 'i' and 'j' in the style component to be a number, or if I go into the console and manually change each of the div's top and left styles, I achieve the desired result. i.e. tiles right next to one another, which leads me to believe that the issue is just in finding a way to run the iterator through and change the 'top' and 'left' as it iterates and returns divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating 20 x 10 x number of items in `flattened` tiles, which is way more than 64.

How did you come up with these numbers? Also keep in mind that the nested loops execute within a `map`, which gives 200 iterations (200 new divs) per element in the `flattened` collection.

If you want an 8x8 checkbord with 64 elements you can do this with a single pass of the map function where column number is `index % 8` and row is `Math.floor(index / 8)`:

```
var Board = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.tiles.map( (tile, idx) => {
        let position = { 
             left : `${ 50 * (idx % 8) }px`, 
             top : `${ 50 * Math.floor(idx/8) }px` 
        };
        return <div className="tile" style={ position }>{ idx }</div>
    })}</div>;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cypued0h/

For a more general case, where the number of columns is configurable:

```
var Board = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.tiles.map( (tile, idx) => {
        let position = { 
        left : `${ 50 * (idx % this.props.columns) }px`, 
        top : `${ 50 * Math.floor(idx / this.props.columns ) }px` 
        };
        return <div className="tile" style={ position }>{ idx }</div>
    })}</div>;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cypued0h/1/

Comment: Why link to JSFiddle when you can just [embed a snippet in your answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: It's pretty humbling to struggle with something and someone comes up with a solution I hadn't even considered, in minutes. This seems right. I see the more general case, what about a case where rows and cols are configurable? i.e. 20 rows, 10 cols. 

Additionally, can you help with the question on styling each block with a different class based on whether it's truthy.

Comment: @Aaron if you set the number of columns you'll get as many rows as needed to accommodate the elements. If you need to restrict the number of rows you can slice the array before rendering.

Comment: @Aaron and the styling part: `className={ "tile " + ( someValue ? "filled" : "") } ` https://jsfiddle.net/cypued0h/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I worked on this all day yesterday and made little progress. I really appreciate your help.